# how to read data from a URL

Tags: perl, url, read-data

Is there a anyway to read data from a URL with SSL after with using

```
tie(*SSL, "Net::SSLeay::Handle", $host, $port);
```

my code below

```
my $a = "POST /login.php HTTP/1.1";
my $b = "Host: www.test.com";
my $c = "Connection: close";
my $e = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
my $f = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
my $g = "Origin: https://www.facebook.com";
my $h = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31";
my $i = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
my $j = "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch";
my $k = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8";
my $l = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3";

my $cookie = "cookie: datr=80ZzUfKqDOjwL8pauwqMjHTa";
my $post = "lsd=AVpD2t1f&display=&enable_profile_selector=&legacy_return=1&next=&profile_selector_ids=&trynum=1&timezone=300&lgnrnd=031110_Euoh&lgnjs=1366193470&email=$user&pass=$user&default_persistent=0&login=Log+In";
my $cl = length($post);
my $d = "Content-Length: $cl";


my ($host, $port) = ("www.test.com", 443);

tie(*SSL, "Net::SSLeay::Handle", $host, $port);




print SSL "$a\n";
print SSL "$b\n";
print SSL "$c\n";
print SSL "$d\n";
print SSL "$e\n";
print SSL "$f\n";
print SSL "$g\n";
print SSL "$h\n";
print SSL "$i\n";
print SSL "$j\n";
print SSL "$k\n";
print SSL "$l\n";
print SSL "$cookie\n\n";

print SSL "$post\n";
```

Comment: Is this for educational purposes? Why do you not simply use LWP?

Comment: i want to testing my website . the code above i using blueforce and check by getting data

Answer (score 2):

The [synopsis](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSLeay::Handle#SYNOPSIS) of Net::SSLeay::Handle suggest to simply `print` to the handle (emphasis mine).

```
use Net::SSLeay::Handle qw/shutdown/;
my ($host, $port) = ("localhost", 443);

tie(*SSL, "Net::SSLeay::Handle", $host, $port);

print SSL "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n";
shutdown(\*SSL, 1);
print while (<SSL>);                          # <------- here
close SSL;
```

Comment: sorry i still dont understand . i want to get content data using like this code with SSL that i post 

my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new(
        ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 },
    );

    my $response = $ua->get('https://www.facebook.com/suond.loyal');
    print $response->content, "\n";

Comment: @SeaklengSay did you try this?